# How to change background color of a cell in Devexpress Grid when i click select them?

Tags: c#, devexpress, xtragrid

I have a `DevExpress XtraGrid` with 7 columns.

I want to change the cell background color when i click select. I try with `GridViewInfo` but it only takes the columns that are visible on the screen. But I want to do for all the columns. (Not with `RowCellStyle`) Do you have a solution for that?

```
private static DataTable CreateTable(int RowCount)
{
    DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
    tbl.Columns.Add("Question", typeof(string));
    tbl.Columns.Add("A", typeof(string));
    tbl.Columns.Add("B", typeof(string));
    tbl.Columns.Add("C", typeof(string));
    tbl.Columns.Add("D", typeof(string));
    tbl.Columns.Add("E", typeof(string));
    for (int i = 0; i < RowCount; i++)
        tbl.Rows.Add(new object[] { String.Format("Question: {0}", i), "", "", "", "", "" });
    return tbl;
}

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    gridControl1.DataSource = CreateTable(5);
}

private void gridView1_RowCellStyle(object sender, RowCellStyleEventArgs e)
{
    GridView View = sender as GridView;
    if (e.Column.FieldName == "A" || e.Column.FieldName == "B" || e.Column.FieldName == "C" || e.Column.FieldName == "D" || e.Column.FieldName == "E")
    {
        if (e.RowHandle >= 0)
        { 
            e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Green;
            //gridView1.Appearance.FocusedCell.BackColor = Color.Green;
        } 
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: The image does not represent the datatable from your code. What are the types of columns with captions "1 T2", "2 T3"....?

Comment: I'm using my language (Vietnamese), I will translate as follows:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30166372/vb-net-xtragrid-change-cell-color-after-its-value-is-edited

Comment: Do you also want to save the states of clicked column? I mean if you mouse hover to other cell it will restore to its old state.

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle `GridView.ShownEditor` event.

```
private void GrdView_ShownEditor(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  GridView view = (GridView)sender;
  GrdView.FocusedRowHandle = view.FocusedRowHandle;
  GrdView.FocusedColumn = GrdView.FocusedColumn;

  GrdView.ShowEditor();

  dynamic editor = GrdView.ActiveEditor;

  //editor.Enabled = False

  editor.BackColor = Color.Blue;

  //view.Invalidate()
}
```

But as soon as you hover to other cell it will restore cell to its last state. In this case you need to handle `GridView.HiddenEditor`.

See [this devex](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_ShownEditortopic) documentation.